# Cannot process an element with node type "Text". Only Element and EndElement node types are supported' in azure devops release

Tags: azure-devops

I’m performing a release and deployment for a DotNet application in Azure Devops.

While performing the release, the ‘Deploy IIS App’ task throwing an error as

```
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException:
The background process reported an error with the following message:
Cannot process an element with node type "Text".
Only Element and EndElement node types are supported.

at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.OutOfProcessUtils.ProcessData(String data, DataProcessingDelegates callbacks).
```

Could you please help me to resolve this error, I need to deploy my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the similar issue with Azure Devops and the work around is to uncheck "Deploy in Parallel" option from Deploy IIS App Task.Hope this helps you.

Comment: Unticking the `Deploy in parallel` box worked for me too, thanks!