# How can I modify my code to negate this error?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, streaming

Here is my function, on file streamMonitor.ps1

```
function streamMonitor {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [string]$directoryPath,
        [string]$scriptToRestartPath
    )

    while ($true) {
        Write-Host "Monitoring directory: $directoryPath"
        Write-Host "Script to restart: $scriptToRestartPath"
        # Get the current time
        $currentTime = Get-Date

        # Get the latest creation time of any file in the directory
        $latestCreationTime = Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath -Recurse |
            Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
            Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1 |
            ForEach-Object { $_.CreationTime }

        # Ensure $latestCreationTime is not $null
        if ($null -eq $latestCreationTime) {
            Write-Host "No files found in the directory."
            return
        }

        # Check if the latest write time is within the last 30 seconds
        $timeDifference = New-TimeSpan -Start $latestCreationTime -End $currentTime
        if ($timeDifference.TotalSeconds -gt 30) {
            # No changes in the last 30 seconds, restart the specified script
            Write-Host "No changes detected within the last 30 seconds. Restarting script..."
            Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c `"$scriptToRestartPath`"" -NoNewWindow
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Changes detected within the last 30 seconds. No action taken."
        }

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        continue
    }
}
```

Here is the script at which I invoking parallel instances of my function on a separate PowerShell file:

```
$streamMonitor = @(
    @{
        directoryPath       = 'C:\pathto\stream2'
        scriptToRestartPath = 'C:\pathto\stream2.bat'
    }
    @{
        directoryPath       = 'C:\pathto\stream3'
        scriptToRestartPath = 'C:\pathto\stream3.bat'
    }
    @{
        directoryPath       = 'C:\pathto\stream1'
        scriptToRestartPath = 'C:\pathto\stream1.bat'
    }
)
    
$streamMonitor | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Job {
        . C:\pathto\streamMonitor.ps1
        streamMonitor @using:_
    }
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
[localhost] There is an error processing data from the background process. Error reported: Cannot process 
an element with node type "Text". Only Element and EndElement node types are supported..
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2102,PSSessionStateBroke
```

Comment: Are you able to install modules? I'm certain using `Start-ThreadJob` instead of `Start-Job` will give a better perspective on what the issue could be or perhaps even solve it

Comment: perhaps related https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/start-job-powershell-parallelisation-not-working-i/489390 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370359/cannot-process-an-element-with-node-type-text-only-element-and-endelement-nod if you're using azure pipelines

Comment: a minor, unrelated to the question, suggestion:  use `$latestCreationTime = Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath -File | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending -Top 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CreationTime`. Should result into some improvement if there are many files, as most filtering is done at source by GCI and Sort-Object

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon this did the job, thanks again!

Comment: @sirtao thanks for the insight! I will try that out!